# iOS Reachability Not Recognizing When Host is Removed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, reachability

I am building an application and trying to check and see if a device is still available on the network (by connecting to the devices IPAddress). I am using reachability to confirm that it is available.

When I network access for the iOS device (turn on airplane mode for example) everything works properly, but if I remove the device from the network, reachability does not seem to notice the change.

It seems like reachability is caching the results, and not seeing the update.

Comment: Please check your NSNotification observer. If it is getting removed while going into Background or coming to foreground.

Comment: You can check apple Reachabilty sample class: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use reachability then!

Use this bit of code instead which works a treat;

```
NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
wait(25000);
if (connected == NULL) {

NSLog(@"Not Connected"); 
//Code to show if not connected

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Oops! You aren't connected to the Internet." 
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

} else {
NSLog(@"Connected Successfully!");
//Any other code for successful connection
}
```

Comment: I was having the same issue with Nathan.  Your solution is simple but work any time!  the only thing I want to add is to use the new stringWithContentsOfURL format.
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

Comment: I would stay away from waiting 25 seconds to allow for the result to return.

Answer (score 2):

The `SCReachability` API only checks if the local hardware is configured such that it could reach the specified address; it does not actually attempt to reach it. To determine if the target is alive and kicking, you must attempt to open a connection to it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5563306).  While the pixelbit's answer is viable, burtlo is right to bring up that just waiting 25 seconds isn't a great idea.  Using the NSURLConnection is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Apple updated the Reachabilty class file. You can test it with latest Xcode.
here is link: 
[Apple Reachabilty Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html)

I tested with Xcode 8.3.1 on iPhone 6 version 10.3.1.
It will notify user for change in network status.