# Handling Broken Links in UIwebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, broken-links

I am loading a webpage using `UIWebView` in my iOS 7 application. I have a few broken links in my webpage.

When I click on these links, I want to intimate the user with an `alertView`. I implemented the following delegates but no response was obtained.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Note: These delegate methods get called when I click on non-broken links.

So is there any way by which the `webView` can respond to broken links too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does broken links means? are you referring to 404 error ?

Comment: Broken Links-The resource is not available on the server OR that link might be pointing to other pages which are not present on server right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    int status = [[[webView request] valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Status"] intValue];
    if (status == 404) {

    }
}
```

From here you can check status. Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: Yes you are right.But this delegate does not respond when i click on broken links.Thats my issue.If it was called,then yes, we can check the current status and perform the task accordingly.But i am hit with the constraint of UIWebView not responding when such links are clicked

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to consume `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

You should:

1. Get the url from request.
2. Send an asynchronous request to the url.
3. Check if you get response. If not response cancel this request otherwise allow it by returning `TRUE`.

Have a look at how you can send request.

[Checking reachability again a specific page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616914/checking-reachability-against-a-specific-page-in-a-url)

[Is it wise to use Reachability to check for a remote host's availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756376/is-it-wise-to-use-reachability-to-check-for-a-remote-hosts-availability)

Using this way you can cancel request and inform user that the specified page is not available. You can also **check** for **HTTP Status Code** of **response** which is usually **200**, if you have a valid response.

Hope it helps!

**Another way** is to handle it from your webpage itself, i.e., redirect it to some common page that says the page is unavailable and a `back` to redirect it to the previous page.

**EDIT:**

Try this code in separate project `h` file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
```

and in `m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

     UIWebView *wbWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.view addSubview:wbWebView];
    [wbWebView setDelegate:self];   // <------------- set delegate
    [wbWebView loadRequest:request];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"request loading... %@", [request URL].absoluteString);

    // TODO : Validate here
    // If validated then return TRUE otherwise false;
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"request finished loading");
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"request failed loading");
}
```

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: delegate method is not invoked when i click on such links.Only for normal links will this delegate gets called.No response is obtained from the UIWebView delegates.